# Trying to pass a String with a certain format

Tags: jquery, json

I know the format that I am trying to pass and it should look like this:

```
[{"blah.png"},{"blah2.png"}]
```

but instead i am returning this:

```
["blah.png","blah2.png"]
```

Here is my code:

```
var filesObj = [];

$('#fileList .files .fileName').each(function () {
    var name = $(this).text();
    filesObj.push(name);
});

console.log(filesObj);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/dat/Controller",
    data: JSON.stringify(filesObj),
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The top format isn't valid JSON; You're delcaring objects with keys and no value. What are you actually after?

Comment: I am trying to `POST` a string object to a `List<string>` server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested in the future...

The way I fixed this was not by the format of the string but changing the `AJAX` call.

I set up my object like this:

```
var filesObj = [];

$('#fileList .files .fileName').each(function () {
    var name = $(this).text();
    filesObj.push(name);
});
```

This POSTs a string like: `["delete-icon.png","something.exe"]`

The trick was to modify my `AJAX` to `POST` like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/dat/Controller",
    data: JSON.stringify(filesObj),
    contentType: "application/json",
    traditional: true,
    success: function (result) {
        console.log("Success: " + result);
    },
    error: function (result) {
        console.log("Error: " + result);
    }
});
```

Changing `dataType` to `contentType` and adding `traditional: true` seemed to do the trick for me. The reason for this (I believe) is because the actual data that I was posting is technically not `JSON`. I added the `traditional: true` just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

```
[{"blah.png"},{"blah2.png"}]
```

Would not be valid JavaScript or JSON. If you wanted to use objects instead of strings, your loop would look more like this

```
$('#fileList .files .fileName').each(function () {
    var name = $(this).text();
    filesObj.push({"name": name});
});
```

Here, each object has a key, "name", and a value that corresponds to `$(this).text();`

Comment: Unfortunately doing this still does not get me the format that I think I need. My end goal is to pass this into a list object in my C# controller. for some reason it still seems to be returning null.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var filesObj = {files:[]}; //initialize as javascript object

$('#fileList .files .fileName').each(function () {
    var name = $(this).text();
    filesObj.files.push(name);
});

console.log(filesObj);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/FileUpload/ImportCommit",
    data: JSON.stringify(filesObj),
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately doing this still does not get me the format that I think I need. My end goal is to pass this into a list object in my C# controller. for some reason it still seems to be returning null.